# MySQL Databases with Ghost Data?

Tags: php, mysql, plugins

I wrote a PHP tool a while back that allows us to automatically setup free MySQL Databases for our customers in an internal standalone installation. It works fine but we recently were forced to migrate the databases due to hardware failure.

After doing so, the existing MySQL databases seem to have some type of ghost data in them. We cannot see these tables in PHPMyAdmin but it is detected by our customer's plugins and some of our own tools.

I have never heard of MySQL Ghost Data like this before and was wondering if anyone has any idea where this comes from or how to fix it?

Comment: I think the key lies in the manner you used to migrate the databases. Could you share with us more information of how you went about this?

Comment: Could it be that the user account used by phpMyAdmin doesn't have access rights for those databases/tables?

Comment: As I did not handle the migration, I will check on the user account for phpMyAdmin and check with the tech who did handle it and post back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ghost Data.. interesting!
I am not sure, but I think you are talking about INFORMATION_SCHEMA, which provide access to database metadata. [Check This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html)

And, wherever you migrate to, most of the databases have these metadata-tables.
Ex: SQL SERVER has sysobjects or sysusers tables and many more...